# Aggrid vue i18n: Grid header name not translated without refresh after change language

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, vue-i18n, ag-grid-vue

I'm using i18n for localization in my project but whenever i change the language, all page's translate is okay except grid header names! Its getting normal when i refresh the page.How can fix this situation without refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by calling the `refreshHeader` function on the reader API.
try this :

```
this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
```

where the gridApi is the API object you get from the `onGridReady` event params.

EDIT, how to get the gridApi :

the gridApi u get from the params of the onGridReady method being called by the AgGrid component.
if you are using reactJs, an attribute named onGridReady in your agGrid component would accept that function.

```
onGridReady = params => {
    this.gridApi = params.api
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi
...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, first gridApi doesn't include refreshHeader function even I tried the function in my grid and did'nt work. Can you explain more that how can i use ? For example: I change the language on my navbar and I emitted function for refresh header i used "this.gridApi.refreshHeader();"  where the gridApi i reach .

Comment: @ÖzlemUslu the refresh header function would rebuild headers, and execute the `headerValueGetter` on each header if it exists. how are you doing the internationalization ? if you are doing it elsewhere (other than the headerValueGetter), the `refreshHeader` method may not help you

Comment: Normally I use "headerName" for definition and localization for header name. I used like you said "headerValueGetter" and it works! Thank you so much :)  I am not sure if it would be efficient to use it only for name localization in the whole project. I mean "headerValueGetter",  I have a lot grids. Does it affect performance ?

Comment: `headerValueGetter` only gets called if you render the whole agGrid component, or if you call refresh headers. it does actually make the page stutter for half a second so, don't overuse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using headerName, maybe try to use computed() function to get ColDef

Ex:

```
const colDef = computed(() => // coldef here)
```